# Skeleton killed by its own arrow achievement?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, achievements, minecraft-data-packs

I would like to make an achievement for killing a skeleton with a reflected arrow. How would I go about doing that? There does not seem to be any noticeable NBT data difference other than owner.

There needs to be a check for if the arrow is deflected, otherwise players would likely get the achievement when skeletons kill each other, and also the ownership of arrows **are not** converted to the player when they are deflected, becuase I did not get the monster hunter achievement with this method.

Perhaps the game could check if a skeleton dies by an arrow shot by one with the same UUID?